# What kind of hardships impacting a personal journey might be permissible to include in NDSEG application?

Tags: graduate-admissions

According to the prompt,

> describe the Fellows personal journey to get where they are today (e.g., 1st to receive PHD, 1st to go to college, worked multiple position while achieving degree, what it took personally to get to where they are, etc…)

I am wondering what kind of hardships impacting a personal journey might be permissible to include.
For example, would underlying health conditions impacting school be appropriate? Would mental health issues (i.e PTSD) from personal previous abuse be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Only include information directly relating to the selection criteria.  They want to see that you will contribute to the announced needs and that your research will be excellent.

It would be beneficial to say

> My experience with PTSD demonstrates that I am excellent at *useful skill* which demonstrates I will achieve *desired outcome*.

It's up to you to know your personal experiences and figure out how to relate them to your strengths.

When the instructions say they want your "story," then at least for physical sciences/engineering they are being misleading.  When people in the physical sciences/engineering say "story" they do not mean a narrative or emotional argument.  A "story" is an explanation of why something is useful or innovative.